# SQLAlchemy - Boolean Hybrid Attribute

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to be able to run the following SQLAlchemy queries:

```
q_done = Batch.query.filter(Batch.done)
q_running = Batch.query.filter(~Batch.done)
```

But I can't wrap my head around writing the `expression` corresponding to my `done` hybrid attribute.

SQLAlchemy models:

```
class Action(db.Model):
    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    action      = db.Column(db.String(32))
    done        = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    batch       = db.relationship(Batch.__name__, backref='actions')

class Batch(db.Model):
    id                = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name              = db.Column(db.String(255), default='unknown')

    @hybrid_property
    def total_actions(self):
        return db.session.query(Action).join(Action.batch).filter(Batch.id == self.id).count()

    @hybrid_property
    def finished_actions(self):
        return db.session.query(Action).join(Action.batch).filter(Batch.id == self.id).filter(Action.done).count()

    @hybrid_property
    def done(self):
        return self.total_actions == self.finished_actions
```

I tried to implemented the corresponding `expression` without much success. It's hard to understand how I can return a boolean query. This is my humble attempt:

```
@done.expression
def done(self):
    total_actions = db.session.query(func.sum(Batch.actions))
    finished_actions = db.session.query(func.sum(Batch.actions.done))
    return db.session.query(Batch).filter(total_actions == finished_actions)
```

Comment: Try calling `.as_scalar()` on the query object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `total_actions` and `finished_actions` are both `hybrid attributes` and thus cannot be used in the `expression` for `done`.

I had to add the corresponding `expression` for each of them that return a query instead of a value.

Here is the complete code:

```
class Action(db.Model):
    id          = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    action      = db.Column(db.String(32))
    done        = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    batch       = db.relationship(Batch.__name__, backref='actions')

class Batch(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def total_actions(self):
        return db.session.query(Action).join(Action.batch).filter(Batch.id == self.id).count()

    @total_actions.expression
    def total_actions(cls):
       return (select([func.count(Action.id)]).
                where(Action.bid == cls.id).
                label("total_actions"))

    @hybrid_property
    def finished_actions(self):
        return db.session.query(Action).join(Action.batch).filter(Batch.id == self.id).filter(Action.done).count()

    @finished_actions.expression
    def finished_actions(cls):
       return (select([func.count(Action.id)]).
                where(Action.bid == cls.id).
                where(Action.done).
                label("finished_actions"))

    @hybrid_property
    def done(self):
       return self.total_actions == self.finished_actions

    @done.expression
    def done(cls):
       return cls.total_actions == cls.finished_actions
```